# How to get past the "Can't pull because it has unmerged file" error message?

Tags: git

I tried to do:

```
git pull origin master
```

It downloaded the files from another repository, now I realized the origin was named as `origin1` for my actual repository .

```
git pull origin1 master
```

But now I am getting

```
can't pull because it has unmerged file.
```

Is there a way I can fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have any work in progress, you can do:

```
git fetch origin1
git reset --hard origin1/master
```

Warning: that will remove any untracked file.

Comment: by untracked file you mean like all the files in my local repository will be overwritten right ?

Comment: @Vikram yes, any local modification not yet committed would be lost.

Comment: when I did the above it says `HEAD is now at ed96b77 working on collection controller`  this is a message i had put when i pushed last time . So now SHould I pull once again ?

Comment: @Vikram no, that just means origin1/master also points to that commit.